# React - Top Level component becomes bloated?

Tags: reactjs

It seems that the component of the app in react cases gets fat really quick. Because I'm storing so many functions that edit my data, is there a design pattern I'm missing for spreading the data throughout the components?
Is there a good article to read about this topic?

Comment: are you using a state management system at all (like redux)?

Comment: Ug, nope not yet, that's the next bit of the tutorials I should read then... Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: if you end up have tons of data edition in your top level component, you are giving it too much responsibility, including your state management. Using a state management system should help you move those out of the way.

Comment: if you use hooks instead of redux is better because redux is getting old and for a developer it's better to use new technologies. and hooks is very easier than redux